# Remove row from DataGridView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

run into a problem, i have a datagrid, columns as follow
One, Two, Multiply

i can delete row buy clicking del KEY on the keyboard but when im trying to program my own remove function it does not work 
and the message im getting is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Here is my code:

```
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NumberData.Items.Remove(NumberData.SelectedItems); 

}

public class Numbers : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private double? _one;
    private double? _two;
    private double? _multiply;
    public double? One { get { return _one; } set { _one = value; UpdateValue(); } }
    public double? Two { get { return _two; } set { _two = value; UpdateValue(); } }
    public double? Multiply
    {
        get { return _multiply; }
        set
        {
            _multiply = value; UpdateValue();
        }
    }

    public Numbers(double? pOne, double? pTwo)
    {
        _one = pOne;
        _two = pTwo;
        _multiply = GetMultiply(); 
    }

    private void UpdateValue()
    {
        _multiply = GetMultiply();

        OnPropertyChanged("One");
        OnPropertyChanged("Two");
        OnPropertyChanged("Multiply");
    }

    private double? GetMultiply()
    {
        return _one * _two;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

public class Collection :  ObservableCollection<Numbers>  
{
    public ObservableCollection<Numbers> Numbers { get; set; }      

    public Collection()
    {
        Numbers = new ObservableCollection<Numbers>();

        //Numbers.Add(new Numbers(1, 2));
        //Numbers.Add(new Numbers(2, 2)); 
    }

    public void AddNumbers(double pOne, double pTwo)
    {
        Numbers.Add(new Numbers(pOne,pTwo));
    }

    public void AddNumbersRow()
    {
        Numbers.Add(new Numbers(null, null));
    }
}

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="NumberData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" LostFocus="StockData_LostFocus" >
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number One" Width="100" Binding="{Binding One, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number Two" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Two, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=\{0:C\}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Multiply, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:C\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="buttonSave" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonAddRow" Content="Add Row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonAddRow_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="buttonRemove" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="411,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonRemove_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You have all those bindings and you aren't just modifying the ObservableCollection?: Why???

Comment: not sure what you are suggesting. so if you explain maybe that is what i should do.

Comment: _"it does not work"_ is not very specific or descriptive.  Do you get an exception?

Comment: yes, i do get exception - > An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have everything set up right, with a single oddity:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Not sure why the ItemsSource is the DataContext. The DataContext should be a View Model class with some `ObservableCollection` property that you then bind to.

But beyond that, since you said your code was working; **you shouldn't be deleting items manually like that**.

Your button should be bound to a command, that goes to the view model and modifies the bound collection. A sample would look like:

```
myObservableCollection.RemoveAt(0);
```

Since its an `ObservableCollection`, the modification will propagate to the UI.

Comment: thanks a lot , you gave me working idea. i solved it .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, i got the idea from your answers , here is what i have done to remove the item

```
if (NumberData.SelectedIndex == -1)
       {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("nothing selected");

       }
       else
       {
           int indexSelected = Convert.ToInt32(NumberData.SelectedIndex);
           mycollection.Numbers.RemoveAt(indexSelected);
       }
```